# Hints to calculate Show $E[X_{1}\vert Y]=\frac{1}{5}(Y-1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-expectation

We roll a fair dice until we reach roll a $6$. Let $Y$ be an RV representing the rolls needed to roll a $6$ and $X_{1}$ be the number of throws wherein we threw a $1$.Show $E[X_{1}\vert Y]=\frac{1}{5}(Y-1)$

I do not know how to progress because the partition formula cannot be used

Edit: Let $V_{i}$ be the number thrown at the $i-$th attempt.

Note that $E[X_{1}\vert \operatorname{rolling a 6 for the first time at Y}]=E[X_{1}\vert \operatorname{rolling not a 6 through to Y-1}]=\sum^{Y-1}_{i=1}1P(V_{i}=1)=(Y-1)\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: $E[X_1|Y] = E[X_1|6\,in\,Y-th\,throw] = E[X_1|Y-1\,throws\,was\,made\,without\,6]$ now it's simple pure logical inference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_i$ is the number of $i$'th you get before getting the first $6$, then
$\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i = Y-1$, now you know that by symmetry $\mathbb E[X_i|Y]$ are equals and independents of $i$, which means that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X_1|Y] &= \frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb E[X_i|Y]\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i\middle|Y\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{5}\mathbb E[Y-1|Y]\\
&= \frac{1}{5}(Y-1)
\end{align*}